# Sort object array by string property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of JavaScript objects

```
let data = [
      { type: 'account', title: 'Robb', subscription: 'ESSENTIAL' },
      { type: 'account', title: 'Bran', subscription: 'ESSENTIAL' },
      { type: 'account', title: 'Arya', subscription: 'FREE' },
      { type: 'article', title: 'The Wall' },
      { type: 'account', title: 'Tyrion', subscription: 'ESSENTIAL' },
    ];
```

The array is already sorted. I want to sort it again by subscription. The requirement is to show ESSENTIAL accounts at the top and leave others as they are. Note that some objects does not have a `subscription` property.

Answer (score 1):

`data.sort((a, b) => a.subscription === "ESSENTIAL" ? 1 : -1);`